# Bash process with 100% cpu usage. How to troubleshoot?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script that is in a runnable state with 100% cpu usage in the user space. Is there a way I can inspect more closely what's causing the issue, without killing the process, such as do a stack trace?

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at your process with `strace`:

```
strace -p <pid_of_your_process>
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the script as `sh -x yourscript`. This will print all the commands it is executing, and you can see where it gets stuck.

You can then eventually add `strace` to the command that slows things down to check its calls to the system functions. That generates loads of output to stderr. You can redirect to a log file like `strace yourprogram 2> log`

Another possibility, which really involves knowing more about the programs which are called, is connecting to the running processes using `gdb`. You can find which process occupies 100% with `top`. Connect to a running program with

```
gdb program 1234   (where 1234 is the `pid` of `program`)
```

Comment: This involves killing the process, which OP explicitly stated he didn't want to do.